# How to check null or empty JSON data in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to check null or empty JSON data in windows phone 8.

I got below result by webclient "e.Result"

Example : {"OverTimeResult":[null]} 
Example : {"OverTimeResult":[]}

Comment: if(e.result!=null) write the rest of your code..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check e.Result, then use

> string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result)

if you want to check OverTimeResult, you shoud parse the json first (see this for example: http://james.newtonking.com/json